# Python list of repeated integers

Tags: python, list

I am trying to index a dataset by creating a list of repeated integers. The data is in a set of 5 so each number will be repeated 5 times until a certain number of rows is reached.
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,...] until 90 terms are reached.

I have considered concatenating lists of 1s, 2s, etc but this is very inefficient. What else can I try for this?

Comment: Is your question how to create such a list? What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question? You may find useful to read the [mcve] documentation and then rephrase your post.

Comment: How did this get so many upvotes if it does not show any effort (Not MCVE), not a clear question, ???

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple list comprehension line for that :

```py
number_of_term = 90
index = [(i//5)+1 for i in range(number_of_term)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

**Code :**

```
arr = [i for i in range(1,91) for j in range(5)]
print(arr)
```

**Output :**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 
, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15 
, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2 
1, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26,  
27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38 
, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 4 
4, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50,  
50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 
 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 62, 62 
, 62, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 6 
8, 68, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74,  
74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 
 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86 
, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use comprehensions to simplify such thing:

```
begin = 1
end = 90
repeatEach = 5

result = [i for i in range(begin, end + 1) for _ in range(repeatEach)]

print(result)
```